# How to use regular express parse file directory hierarchy?

Tags: regex, capturing-group, regex-group

Suppose the file path is "a/b/c/d/e", how can I get a array of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'?
I have consider with this: 
`(?:(.+)/)*?(.+)`
but it get empty string,it is really unexpected.

Comment: You can use `[^/]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this one:

**`/([^\/]+)/g`**

Tested here:

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yK7Igv/1)

Comment: only get 'a' with `new Regex("([^\\/])*[\\/]*");` in c#

Comment: could you please try now ?

Comment: so sad it also return 'a'

Comment: Are you sure about that ? https://regex101.com/r/yK7Igv/1

Comment: I'm not use `/g` in c#, I add it with `Matches` method( before is `Match` method), it works now! thanks

Comment: Could have helped earliar, had you tagged c#